# Can I use python to run a C# script file(.cs)?

Tags: c#, python, halcon, gige-sdk

I'm working with python on a project using OPT GIGE cameras. What I need now is to show the camera vision and capture a frame with my Python script. I didn't find anyway to connect to the  gige camera with opencv in python, so I decide to use halcon to capture the image. But halcon can only export to .cs file  I wonder is there anyway to use python to execute a .cs script?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you confused C# source code file and C# Script file.

The former has a .cs extension and is just a source code file, wich should be included in the project and compiled, and requires .NET Framework or other .NET runtime, depending on the OS version, to run.

The latter has a .csx extension and looks more like what you are looking for - however, it still requires .net libraries. More about .csx files can be found [here](https://dailydotnettips.com/executing-c-scripts-from-command-line-or-c-interactive-windows-in-visual-studio/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25405941/what-are-csx-c-sharp-files-for)

Comment: Thank you for explanation, I'm pretty new in programming, I just got a project required me to do programming. 
so, Halcon can export as .cs file, what should I do to run it in Python? I've checked on a module called subproces but it's a little beyond my knowledge base right now and I'm not quite sure it's the solution.